# Frequency-weighted percentile in dataframe with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I am trying to calculate the percentile ranks of a value in a dataframe, and I also have an associated frequency in the dataframe to weight by. I'm struggling to come up with a solution that will calculate the percentile of the original value as if the overall distribution is that value replicated by the frequency and all the other values replicated by that frequency.

For example:

```
groceries <- tribble(
  ~item, ~price, ~freq,
  "apple",   1, 20,
  "banana",   2, 5,
  "carrot",   3, 1
)

groceries %>% 
    mutate(reg_ptile = percent_rank(price),
           wtd_ptile = weighted_percent_rank(price, wt = freq))

# the expected result would be:

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  item   price  freq reg_ptile wtd_ptile
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 apple      1    20  0.0      0.0
2 banana     2     5  0.5      0.8
3 carrot     3     1  1.0      1.0
```

`percent_rank()` is an actual dplyr function. How would the function `weighted_percent_rank()` be written? Not sure how to make this work in a dataframe and pipes. It would be swell if the solution could also work with groups.

Edit: Using `uncount()` doesn't really work because uncounting the data I'm using would result in 800 billion rows. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::uncount` to expand the number of rows as per frequency to get the weighted percentile, then reduce them back down with `summarize`, as per this regex:

```r
library(dplyr)

groceries <- tribble(
  ~item, ~price, ~freq,
  "apple",   1, 10,
  "banana",   2, 5,
  "carrot",   3, 1
)

groceries %>% 
  tidyr::uncount(freq) %>% 
  mutate(wtd_ptile = percent_rank(price)) %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarize_all(~.[1]) %>%
  mutate(ptile = percent_rank(price))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   item   price wtd_ptile ptile
#>   <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 apple      1     0       0  
#> 2 banana     2     0.667   0.5
#> 3 carrot     3     1       1
```

Note there are different ranking functions you can choose, though in this case the weighted percentile is 0.667 ( `10/(16 - 1)` ), not 0.8

---

**EDIT**

An alternative that does not involve creating billions of rows:

```
groceries %>% 
  arrange(price) %>% 
  mutate(wtd_ptile = lag(cumsum(freq), default = 0)/(sum(freq) - 1))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   item   price  freq wtd_ptile
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 apple      1    10     0    
#> 2 banana     2     5     0.667
#> 3 carrot     3     1     1
```

Comment: Ah I meant to make the freq value for apple 20, but I had it as 10 in the tribble. My bad! I edited the question to reflect that, you can edit your answer if you like.  Gonna test this on my data now, thank you!

Comment: Okay, so the thing about this solution is that using it on my dataset means creating a df with 785 billion rows haha!

Can you think of a solution to get around that, maybe if instead of frequencies we use a proportion? so the data would look like what comes from `groceries %>% mutate(prop = freq/sum(freq))`

Comment: @AdhiR. I didn't realise your numbers were that big! I have added a more efficient alternative.

Comment: Holy shit that worked and it's so simple and easy. Thank you so much.